# eventPreventDefault no evita el envio del formulario

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Este es el código del AJAX en donde recibo las variables del formulario

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">

function enviar() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  var correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
  var asunto = document.getElementById('asunto').value;
  var mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje').value;
  var dataen = 'nombre='+nombre+'&correo='+correo+'&asunto='+asunto+'&mensaje='+mensaje;
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'funciones.php',
    data:dataen,
    success: function(resp) {
      $('#respa').html(resp);
    }
  });
            
  return false;
}

</script>
```

Puse el tipo de botón en *submit* porque si lo pongo en *button*, no se envía la información, solamente poniendo el tipo de botón en *submit*

```
<?php include "funciones.php" ?> 
    <form method="post" name="validFormulario" id="validFormu" onclick="return enviar()">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"  id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="Asunto">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="5" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="button" name="btn_EnviarCorreo" value="Enviar Ahora">
            </div>
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
    <?php mensajeCorreo() ?> 
    <p id="response"></p>
```

---

Agregué el código pero no hace nada.

```
boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

let boton = document.getElementById("envio");

var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
var correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
var asunto = document.getElementById('asunto').value;
var mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Obtén el botón o input por medio de un ID que le declares *y este será el elemento al cual le evaluemos si el usuario da click sobre el*
- Agrégale un listener al evento click
- A la función callback que pasarás como segundo argumento le indicas que prevenga el evento que sería el submit

Entonces tu botón así

```
<input type="button" id="envio" name="btn_EnviarCorreo" value="Enviar Ahora">
```

Posterior en tu JS lo recuperas así

```
let boton = document.getElementById("envio");
```

Le agregas el listener

```
boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    ..................aquí tu código para la petición Ajax
    ...................
});
```

Comment: si funciona, pero al momento de enviar el formulario se envía la información pero se me desliza hacia el inicio y es lo que quiero evitar!!!

Answer (score 0):

**OPCIÓN 1**

El elemento `form` tiene el evento `submit` que se ejecuta cuando se envía el formulario. Para que se ejecute este evento en tu formulario tienes que tener un `<button>` o `<input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>`.

En tu html tenias los elementos mal cerrados, los he corregido y he cambiado `<input type="submit"`. También he quitado el `onclick` del `form`.

```html
<form method="post" name="validFormulario" id="validFormu">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="Asunto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="5" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="btn_EnviarCorreo" value="Enviar Ahora">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
```

En tu script puedes escuchar el evento `submit` y hacer el ajax que deseas hacer. Como veo que incluyes `jQuery` pues lo he usado en mi ejemplo. Quedarías algo así.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">

function enviar(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  var correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
  var asunto = document.getElementById('asunto').value;
  var mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje').value;
  var dataen = 'nombre='+nombre+'&correo='+correo+'&asunto='+asunto+'&mensaje='+mensaje;
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'funciones.php',
    data:dataen,
    success: function(resp) {
      $('#respa').html(resp);
    }
  });
            
  return false;
}

// se selecciona el formulario con el id que has especificado en tu html
// se indica que se quiere escuchar el evento submit sobre este elemento (que es el form)
// y se le pasa la referencia de la función a ejecutar cuando se haga el submit
// automáticamente Javascript pasará el event a tu función cuando la llame

$('#validFormu').submit(enviar);
</script>
```

**OPCIÓN 2**

Si quieres seguir usando el evento `onclick` directamente en el form deberías de añadir el parámetro `event`. Así tu función `enviar` tendrá acceso a dicho parámetro.

```
<form method="post" name="validFormulario" id="validFormu" onclick="return enviar(event)">
```

```
function enviar(event) { ... }
```