# Validar input antes de enviar form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

estoy tratando de configurar un modal pero al dar click en enviar asi los campos esten vacios se procesa el envio con datos null aun cuando en mysql lo tngo configurado para no aceptar datos vacios pero de igual manera se crea una fila con campos vacios.

el modal es el siguiente

```
<div class="modal fade" id="agregarnuevosdatosmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agrega nuevo Dato</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="frmnuevo" autocomplete="on" class="was-validated">

    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CI Cliente</label>
                    <input onkeyup="mayus(this);" pattern="[V,J,G,E]{1}[-][0-9]{7,9}" placeholder="V-12345678 J-12345678 E-12345678" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="ci_cliente" name="ci_cliente" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Debe indicar el numero de Cedula o Rif en el formato V-12345678.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Descripcion</label>
                    <input placeholder="Indique una descripcion de la Operacion" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Plataforma Origen</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="plataforma_origen" name="plataforma_origen" required >
          <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
          <?php
          $query_plataforma = "SELECT * FROM plataforma ORDER BY plataforma";
          $results = mysqli_query($db, $query_plataforma);
          while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($row['plataforma']); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Plataforma Destino</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="plataforma_destino" name="plataforma_destino" required >
          <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
          <?php
          $results = mysqli_query($db, $query_plataforma);
          while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($row['plataforma']); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nro Operacion</label>
                    <input placeholder="Numero de operacion" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="nro_operacion" name="nro_operacion" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Motivo</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="motivo" name="motivo" required >
          <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
          <?php
          $query_motivo = "SELECT * FROM motivo ORDER BY id";
          $results = mysqli_query($db, $query_motivo);
          while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($row['motivo']); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Monto</label>
                    <input placeholder="Monto" type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="monto" name="monto" required>
        <label>Fecha Operacion</label>
                    <input data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="fecha_operacion" name="fecha_operacion" required>
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_admin" name="id_admin" value="<?php echo $id_admin; ?>">
    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
      <button data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" id="btnAgregarnuevo" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El JAVASCRIPT es el siguiente

```
  function validate(){
  var ci_cliente = document.getElementById('ci_cliente').value;

  var ci_clienteRGEX = /^[V,J,G,E]{1}[-][0-9]{7,9}$/;

  var ci_clienteResult = ci_clienteRGEX.test(ci_cliente);

  if(ci_clienteResult == false)
  {
    alertify.error('Verifique el numero de Cliente');
    return false;
  } else
{
  return true;
}

}

  function validarFormVacio(formulario){
      datos=$('#' + formulario).serialize();
      d=datos.split('&');
      vacios=0;
      for(i=0;i< d.length;i++){
          controles=d[i].split("=");
          if(controles[1]=="A" || controles[1]==""){
            vacios++;
          }
      }
      return vacios;
    }



    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnAgregarnuevo').click(function(){
      vacios=validarFormVacio('frmnuevo');
            if(vacios > 0){
                alertify.error("<i class='fa fa-ban'></i> Debes llenar todos los campos!!");
                return false;
            }

            datos=$('#frmnuevo').serialize();
validate(datos);

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:datos,
                url:"../procesos/gestion/agregar.php",
                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){
                        $('#frmnuevo')[0].reset();
            $('#resumengestion').load('../resumengestion.php');
                        $('#tablaDatatable').load('../tablagestion');
                        alertify.success("<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>Agregado con exito :D");
                    }else{
                        alertify.error("<i class='fa fa-ban'></i>Fallo al agregar :(");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Asi como esta no envia si el input esta vacio, pero no he logrado hacer funcionar la function validate() da la alerta de que no se cumple la condicion pero igual manda el dato..!

Comment: Tienes que hacer un preventDefault() del botón para evitar que se procese el evento asociado

Comment: Independientemente de lo que pase en el navegador (javascript) debes validar los datos en el servidor.

Comment: Gracias, Si correcto pero de hecho hago un if isnull en mi php url:"../procesos/gestion/agregar.php", e igual los datos null recibidos del modal son procesados. @BetaM Voy a buscar eso de preventDefault() a ver que tal me va.

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV aqui tienes una respuesta de como usarlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371607/eventpreventdefault-no-evita-el-envio-del-formulario/371610#371610

Comment: Intente sin exito haciendo esto `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnAgregarnuevo').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
   datos=$('#frmnuevo').serialize();

   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:datos,
    url:"../procesos/gestion/agregar.php",
    success:function(r){`

Comment: Tienes muchas cosas por cambiar, empezando por esto: `type="submit"` en el botón de agregar, si vas a usar una función para el evento clic de dicho botón, es mejor declaralo como `type="button"`. Ya que el evento `submit` del formulario se ejecutará siempre que hagas clic en un botón de tipo `submit`. Como bien te sugieren, puedes usar el método `preventDefault()` para evitar el comportamiento por defecto de tu botón. En cuanto a la validación que necesitas, puedes leer [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity). Saludos

Comment: He logrado hacer funcionar una validacion si el input es null pero no he logrado hacer funcionar una validacion de pattern